# remove invalid IRI from RDF file

Tags: dataset, rdf

I have a large RDF file that contains a record having a space in IRI because of which there occur validation errors. the snapshot of the record is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNFw.png)

I want to remove this record from the file. how can I do it?

Comment: what means "large"? The format seems to be RDF/XML which is bad for large data, but using `sed` I'd say with the appropriate regex. But if you already know the line, why can't you remove it? you can delete lines by a given number with `sed` as well.

Comment: by large I mean I can open it in an editor on server(having 515gb ram) make changes in it inside the editor but when I try to save it, it gives me a File save error Invalid response: 413 Request Entity too large. Then I discard the changes and close it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the attribute values are not IRIs, it is not a valid RDF/XML document, and so you cannot (reliably) use methods for working with RDF data. You can however use a XSL Transformation to properly replace any space within the attribute (also added `rdf:about` for good measure) with `%20`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <xsl:template match="@rdf:resource|@rdf:about">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ', '%20')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```